# Speed up 2D numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration

The integral is not really complicated, but does not return a result in reasonable time

```
u[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Cos[a Sin[z]] - BesselJ[0, a], {z, y, x}]
v[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sin[a Sin[z]], {z, y, x}]
w[l_?IntegerQ, a_] := NIntegrate[Exp[I l (y - x)]
  Exp[-(u[x, y, a]^2 + v[x, y, a]^2)/4], {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π}]
```

I would like a couple of values of `w` for low values of `l` and `a=2.2`

```
Table[w[l,2.2],{l,0,3}]
```

Comment: Try this  option ` 
Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}` in `NIntegrate`

Comment: I have you tried u[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Cos[a Sin[z]] - BesselJ[0, a], {z, y, x}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 2]
v[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Sin[a Sin[z]], {z, y, x}, PrecisionGoal -> 2]
w[l_?IntegerQ, a_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[I l (y - x)] Exp[-(u[x, y, a]^2 + v[x, y, a]^2)/
     4], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PrecisionGoal -> 2]` It seems the values are {29.43,3.7463,1.15398,0.11014}

Comment: @Artes Numeric argument implies `"SymbolicProcessing" -> False`, isn't it?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Artes suggestion and adding an explicit precision request:

```
u[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Cos[a Sin[z]] - BesselJ[0, a], {z, y, x}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
  Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
v[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Sin[a Sin[z]], {z, y, x}, PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
  Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
w[l_?IntegerQ, a_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[I l (y - x)] Exp[-(u[x, y, a]^2 + v[x, y, a]^2)/
     4], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
  Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
```

then

```
 ParallelTable[w[l, 2.2], {l, 0, 3}] // Chop
```

> {29.43,3.7463,1.15399,0.11014 }

Comment: Thank you! I've computed what I needed and even managed to play with parameters little bit. Lower precision does not really matter for the plots. However, I do wonder if higher precision can be achieved without compromising the speed too much. When I set the precision goal to 4 and 3, respectively, I could not get the result.